# R: Gephi: manipulating dataframe to use with write.gexf

Tags: r, gephi

I am trying to manipulate a data frame. As an example: say I have a dataframe containing customers and the shops they visit:

```
df = data.frame(customers = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                shop_visited = c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "Z"))
customers shop_visited
        a            X
        b            X
        b            Y
        c            X
        c            Z
```

Summarizing this dataframe:

- one customer (`b`) shops at `X` and also at `Y`;
- one customer (`b`) shops at `Y` and also at `X`;
- one customer (`c`) shops at `X` and also at `Z`;
- one customer (`c`) shops at `Z` and also at `X`

Or, more succinctly:

```
relations = data.frame(source = c("X","Y", "X", "Z"), 
                       target = c("Y","X","Z","X"))
 source target
      X      Y
      Y      X
      X      Z
      Z      X
```

I am looking for a method that will be able to do the transformation `df -> relations`. The motivation behind this is that I can then use `relations` as the `edges` argument in `write.gexf`. Cheers for any help.

Comment: Is this what you're after? `library(igraph); 
g <- graph.data.frame(relations); 
write.graph(g, file="g.graphml", format="graphml")` then you get a graphml file that you can open in Gephi. Or do you really need a gexf file?

Comment: Trying to get it as a `gexf` file is more indicative of my naivety regarding alternatives than anything else. I'll check out the `igraph` package now. Cheers

Comment: The igraph package manual seems weighty so if this is a possible solution, it'll take some time for me to digest; is igraph a package you recommend learning? Also, I may be wrong, but in your above code, it doesn't look like at any point you've obtained `relations` from `df`?!

Comment: To be honest I don't use it much (don't have much need) and also find the documentation rather inscrutable. But like most things `R`, it's got a big group of expert users, some of them active here, so it's easy to get help, that's why I stick with it. I think the `sna` package might have some overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(customers = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                 shop_visited = c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "Z"))

#create an identifier df
dfnames <- data.frame(i = as.numeric(df$shop_visited), 
                      shop_visited = df$shop_visited)

library(tnet)
tdf       <- as.tnet( cbind(df[,2],df[,1]),type =  "binary two-mode tnet" )
relations <- projecting_tm(tdf, method = "sum")

# match original names
relations[["i"]] <- dfnames[ match(relations[['i']], dfnames[['i']] ) , 'shop_visited']
relations[["j"]] <- dfnames[ match(relations[['j']], dfnames[['i']] ) , 'shop_visited']

# clean up names
names(relations) <- c("source" , "target", "weight")


#> relations
#  source target weight
#1      X      Y      1
#2      X      Z      1
#3      Y      X      1
#4      Z      X      1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting stuff. If anyone else is reading this post, they might find the following website useful: http://toreopsahl.com/

Comment: Quick question regarding your answer: `cbind(df[,2],df[,1])` converts the columns to integer values (if they are `factors` originally`). Why is this? Also, can I check that having integer values is necessary for the `projecting_tm` function to work?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look to the function `edge.list` of `rgexf`(http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgexf/docs/edge.list). Using your example it would be something like this

library(rgexf)

```
# Your data
df = data.frame(customers = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                shop_visited = c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "Z"))

# Getting nodes and edges
df2 <- edge.list(df)
```

Looks like this

```
> df2
$nodes
  id label
1  1     1
2  2     2
3  3     3

$edges
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    3    1
[5,]    3    3
```

Finally, you can use this to write a GEXF graph

```
# Building the graph
write.gexf(nodes=df2$nodes, edges=df2$edges)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/gexf.xsd" version="1.2">
  <meta lastmodifieddate="2013-08-06">
    <creator>NodosChile</creator>
    <description>A graph file writing in R using "rgexf"</description>
    <keywords>gexf graph, NodosChile, R, rgexf</keywords>
  </meta>
  <graph mode="static">
    <nodes>
      <node id="1" label="1"/>
      <node id="2" label="2"/>
      <node id="3" label="3"/>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge id="0" source="1" target="1" weight="1.0"/>
      <edge id="1" source="2" target="1" weight="1.0"/>
      <edge id="2" source="2" target="2" weight="1.0"/>
      <edge id="3" source="3" target="1" weight="1.0"/>
      <edge id="4" source="3" target="3" weight="1.0"/>
    </edges>
  </graph>
</gexf>
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt george dot vega at nodoschile.org

Best!

George (creator of `rgexf`)