# R: sna (social network analysis) package: data frame to adjacency matrix

Tags: r, sna

I'm hoping for some more transformation help. Say I have a data frame:

```
df = data.frame(source = c("a","a","b"), 
                target = c("b","c","d"), 
                weight = c(1,1,1))
```

where the row: `source = i | target = j | weight = w` denotes a directed edge of weight `w` from node `i` to node `j`.
Given an arbitrary data frame of this form, I am looking for a procedure to investigate the components of the induced graph `G`. Having read a comment by Ben on this question by me:

[R: Gephi: manipulating dataframe to use with write.gexf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173990/r-gephi-manipulating-dataframe-to-use-with-write-gexf)

I checked out the package `sna` which seemed to have what I was looking for in the form of the function `component.dist`. So my question is 'how can I transform my data frame into a suitable form for the `dat` argument of the `component.dist` function (or is there a more 'optimum' way of approaching this problem?)' I tried the following code:

```
xtabs(weight ~ source + target, data = df)
```

but this has obvious shortfalls (e.g. it doesn't form an `nrow(df)` by `nrow(df)` matrix).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find this result when first searching the internet regarding the above question, however, I have just come across it now:

[How to calculate adjacency matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849835/how-to-calculate-adjacency-matrices-in-r)

From first inspection, looks like it answers my  question.