# R: using regexf. How to visualize XLM code behind write.gexf

Tags: r, function, gephi

I have a very simple question. Running `rgexf` in R I use the code

```
require(rgexf)
vertices <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1,10),seq(1,10)))
colnames(vertices) <- c('Id','Label')
edges <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(5,1,2),c(1,1,3)))
colnames(edges) <- c('Source','Target')
```

to import to Gephi a graph called 'testgex.gexf' with nodes resp. edges given in `vertices` resp. `edges`. To do so I run the function

```
write.gexf(output='testgex.gexf',nodes=vertices,edges=edges,defaultedgetype = "undirected")
```

whose output in R is just

```
GEXF graph successfully written at:
...
```

where the dots are the path of 'testgex.gexf'.

I would like to visualize the XLM code behind 
write.gexf, instead. This is  shown, for example, in @gvegayon 's answer in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173990/r-gephi-manipulating-dataframe-to-use-with-write-gexf/18087543#18087543) or
at the [Bitbucket rgexf page](https://bitbucket.org/gvegayon/rgexf/wiki/Home).

How to do this?

Comment: just dont include the `output=testgexf.gexf` or you can open the .gexf file in a text editor

Comment: that was the secret! :) Thank you very much: please feel free to update your comment into an answer. I would gladly upvote & flag it.

Comment: glad i could help.. this is still in regard to your import into gephi correct? maybe we should put a link between the two? not exactly sure how to do that tho =(

Comment: yep...you found the link :) My approach now is to have a look at the write.gexf output and try to see if there is some hint there. I spent much time to check all str(), class() etc of nodes / edges data.frames but I am still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just dont include the `output=testgexf.gexf` or you can open the .gexf file in a text editor