# Saving nodes and edges into different csv files

Tags: r, csv, igraph

After producing the nodes and edges for a graph like this:

```
df <- structure(list(book1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("refid1", "refid2", 
"refid3", "refid7"), class = "factor"), book2 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid1", "refid3"), class = "factor"), 
    book3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid1", 
    "refid2", "refid4"), class = "factor"), book4 = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid1", "refid3", "refid4"), class = "factor"), 
    book5 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid2", 
    "refid6"), class = "factor"), book6 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid1", "refid2"), class = "factor"), 
    book7 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "refid1", 
    "refid5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("book1", "book2", 
"book3", "book4", "book5", "book6", "book7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(tidyr)


g<- df %>% 
  gather(key = "From", "To", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame()
```

How is it possible to save node and edges into different csv files?

Comment: What exactly do you want for your output as `get.edgelist(g)` gives the nodes and edges (but that is just the same as `df %>%   gather(key = "From", "To", na.rm = TRUE)`) and if you want a list of the nodes suppose you could use `V(g)$name` but you can also get that from `df`

Comment: Can you give the desired output for this input? What exactly do you want in each of the output files?

Comment: @user20650 I would like to use the structure of graph in order to insert the files to gephi software for graphs.

Comment: if the actual question is how to move an igraph to gephi then https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgexf/index.html might be useful. Perhpas also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173990/r-gephi-manipulating-dataframe-to-use-with-write-gexf