# Convert R data into a .GEXF format

Tags: r, csv

My first attempt at building a bipartite graph of co-authors' PubMed publications (226 records). The following is a sample of the input file (just one CSV line):

```
11810598;Chêne G, Angelini E, Cotte L, Lang JM, Morlat P, Rancinan C, May T, Journot V, Raffi F, Jarrousse B, Grappin M, Lepeu G, Molina JM;2002;Mar;Role of long-term nucleoside-analogue therapy in lipodystrophy and metabolic disorders in human immunodeficiency virus-infected patients.
```

```
> InputFile = 'JMMolina_PubMed.csv'

    # Read the CSV input file into the initial JMMpubs data frame

> setwd('~/Dropbox/R')
> JMMpubs <- read.csv(file=InputFile , header =
> FALSE , sep = ";" , strip.white = TRUE) 

> names(JMMpubs) <- c("ID","AuthList", "Year", "Month", "Title")

    # build a new data frame IdAuth with one Id line for each coauthor
    # therefor the first article which has 13 co-authors will generate 13 lines with the same Id

> Authors <- strsplit(as.character(JMMpubs$AuthList), split = ", ")

> IdAuth <- data.frame(Id = rep(JMMpubs$ID, sapply(Authors,length)), Author = unlist(Authors))

    # Now I would like to export this data to Gephi

    # The nodes of the graph should be the UNIQUE names in Authors

> UniqueAuthors <- unique(unlist(Authors))
```

The edges of the graph should be each row of `IdAuth`. I would like to associate the year of the publications `JMMpubs$Year` to each edge (to paint recent edges red and older ones in paler hues).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. My solution has been the following.

For this to work you will as far as I can tell need to reshuffle your data a bit. 
If I understand correctly you need the authors who's connected to an ID. 
The original answer is on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177624/8080865 by user1317221_G

I would set up DF as:

```
df3<-data.frame(Author = c("fawf", "ewew", "wewe", "wrewe", "zare")
                    ID= "11", "11", "11"... etc)´

###TNET solution WoRKS
#create an identifier df for each author
dfnames <- data.frame(i = as.numeric(df3$Id), 
                      value = df$author)

library(tnet)
tdf       <- as.tnet( cbind(df3[,1],df3[,2]), type="binary two-mode tnet")
relations <- projecting_tm(tdf, method = "sum")


# match original names
relations[["i"]] <- dfnames[match(relations[['i']], dfnames[['']] ) , 'value']
relations[["j"]] <- dfnames[match(relations[['j']], dfnames[['i']] ) , 'value']

# clean up names
names(relations) <- c("source" , "target", "weight")
```

I hope this helps you figure out your answer?